# ng-repeat doesn't display even if the data is there

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm creating a basic Website in stack MEAN, and I have some issue with a ng-repeat that won't display a thing. What is strange is when I do something similar in another project, it displays without any problem.

Here is the HTML of the page :

```
    <!-- POST.HTML -->

<div class="row" ng-app ="myapp">
<div class = "col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-6 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-6" ng-controller="postController as post">

    <div class = "row">
        <strong> Username: </strong>
        <input type = "text" ng-model ="post.newPost.Author" class = "form-control" placeholder="Enter your username">
    </div>

    <div class = "row">
        <strong> Content </strong>
        <input type = "text" ng-model = "post.newPost.Content" class= "form-control" placeholder="Write a short text about your humor !">
    </div>

    <button ng-click = "post.Post()" > Post your message  ! </button>

<div> 
    <h4> Posts </h4>
        <li ng-repeat = "message in post.messages">

            <blockquote>
                <strong> Title : {{message._id}} </strong>
                  <!--  {{message.content}} -->
              <!--  <cite class="clearfix">—{{message.author}}</cite> -->
            </blockquote>
        </li>

</div>
</div>
```

And the script associated :

```
(function(){
angular.module("myapp")
.controller("postController", ["$http", function($http){
    $http.get("/api/message/getAll/").then(function(response){
        this.messages = response.data;
        console.log(this.messages);
    });

    this.Post = function(){
        console.log("Post() function called");
        var newPost = this.newPost;
        console.log(newPost);
        $http.post("/api/message/post/", newPost)
            .success(function(response){
            this.messages.push(newPost);


        })

    }

}])
})();
```

I'm sure that the controller is active into this html page as I can submit things without a problem and my Back end doesn't have any issue (I can do request with HTTP REST client). 
Furthermore, as I logged in the console this.messages, I can see there is the right data :

[Image of my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdLjt.png)

The data is logged 3 times because I refreshed the page that much time. And I made sure there was an _id attributes to every object of my data tab. 
I really don't see the problem as every tuto seems to do the same things. It looks like this.messages simply loose its data instantly after being filled with the request.

Does anyone has an idea of what occured ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.controller("postController", ["$http", function($http){
    $http.get("/api/message/getAll/").then(function(response){
        this.messages = response.data;
        console.log(this.messages);
    });
```

this.message is in the $http context, not in the controller context, so not available inside your view nor in your controller.

A common solution ([and best practice](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)) is to use the view model (vm) concept:

```
.controller("postController", ["$http", function($http){
    var vm = this;
    vm.messages = [];
    $http.get("/api/message/getAll/").then(function(response){
        vm.messages = response.data;
    });
```

EDIT:

The keyword `this` is available throughout the controller.
Inside `$http`, the context changes. Using `this` doesn't reference the controller anymore but the function called inside `$http.get.then`

A javascript variable (`var vm`) has a "larger" scope than `this` and its reference doesn't change inside `$http`.

So pushing `controller.this` inside `var vm` makes this available throughout the controller using `vm`.

On the HTML side, with the `controllerAs` syntax (you called your controller `post`) you make the instance of the controller (`this`) available to `$scope.post`

`post` becomes the `this` of the controller if you want.

Comment: It worked really well with the vm ! Thank you very much !

But I still don't get how it works :
I call in my html "message in post.messages" and only have a var vm.messages in the script but it works somehow ?
Why don't I have to call "message in post.vm.message" in my html ?

Comment: Note, the var `vm` is used only in JS file, in your HTML file, you use your named variable in `ControllerAsSyntax`, in this case "post". Then `post.message`.

Comment: @Alburkerk, I tried to edit the answer with some explanation. Hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like you're referring the **post** as controllerAs in the routes.
You are pushing the values in the wrong scope variable. You should use the dedicated $scope so you can trace your assignment better. Following should work.

```
(function(){
    angular.module("myapp").controller("postController", ["$scope","$http", function($scope, $http){
      $http.get("/api/message/getAll/").then(function(response){
      $scope.messages = response.data;
      console.log(this.messages);
    });

    this.Post = function(){
      console.log("Post() function called");
      var newPost = this.newPost;
      console.log(newPost);
      $http.post("/api/message/post/", newPost)
        .success(function(response){
        $scope.messages.push(newPost);
    })

}
}])})();
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should keep break point in browser by doing inspect element and check what exact response you are getting in `.then` function.

please let us know what format of data you are getting on

```
 $http.post("/api/message/post/", newPost)
            .success(function(response){
            this.messages.push(newPost);
             // add break point here
             //new post -- what object you are getting here
        })
```

Comment: It should be a comment, since it isn't an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting this.messages = response.data in the resolve of the $http.get where "this" refers to that context and not the controller context.  To get around this set a var to this and associate messages with that var, like this:

```
var vm = this;
$http.get("/api/message/getAll/").then(function(response) {
  vm.messages = response.data;
  console.log(this.messages);
});
```

Comment: You put a quote and extra parenthesis.

Comment: Good catch @developer033